# grab without regex?

Tags: php, substr, strip

I have a url that I want to grab the values for the variable "key2"

```
http://google.com/dyn_v8/flash/nice-323.swf?file=http://www.yahoo.com/sda/vdsd.ashx?key2=0038003500000077002a001300790002001d0026000e00250008
```

I simply want to grab just: 0038003500000077002a001300790002001d0026000e00250008 via php.

Please help, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Get the location of the last `=` sign, and take everything after it:

```
$result = substr($str, strrpos($str, '=') + 1);
```